# Can only read first value from form list using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I´m trying to build a shopping cart in jQuery and PHP but cannot read values from form list.
When trying to get value from the form that is submitted i only get values from 
the first form in the list view.

Please look at behaviour here: 
http://www.adlertz.se/index.php?op=prodlist&katID=9&sidemenu=menushop

Click buy on ex. the middle, you get value from first.

Please help me with this, i have benn looking for solution for three days.
Probably a simple problem but i cant find the answer anywhere :| !!!.

Many thanks in advance!

```
     function prodlist(){
$katID = $_GET['katID'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop_prod WHERE kategoriID=$katID");

while ($rad=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<div class=\"shop_prod_list\">";
        echo "<div class=\"shop_prod_list_tmb\"><img src=\"shop/images/prod_images_tmb/".$rad['prodID'].".png\" alt=\"\"></div>";

        echo "<form id=\"addcartform\" class=\"addcartform\" method=\"post\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prodID\" id=\"prodID\" value=\"".$rad['prodID']."\" />";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"shop_prod_list_kundvagn\" value=\"\" id=\"addcart\"/>";
        echo "</form>";

    echo "</div>";
}
echo "<div id=\"search_results\"></div>";
```

}

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

$(".addcartform").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    addcart(); 
});
```

});

```
   function addcart(){ 

var prodID=(this).document.getElementById('prodID').value; <-(Reads value but only the first)

$.post("functions/cart.php", {prodID : prodID}, function(data){
    if (data.length>0){ 
        $("#search_results").show();    
        $("#search_results").html(data);
    } 
})
```

}

```
   <?php
  include "db_config.php";
  include "db_connect.php";

$prodID = strip_tags(substr($_POST['prodID'],0, 100));
$prodID = mysql_escape_string($prodID);

echo $prodID ." is added.";
```

?>

Comment: that is because you have to use unique ID for each item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead of id

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prodID\" class=\"prodID\" value=\"".$rad['prodID']."\" />";
```

Send the element which was clicked to your function

```
$(".addcartform").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    addcart(this); //this line
});
```

Then use that element to find the input with your class

```
function addcart(element){ 

    var prodID = $(element).find('.prodID').val();  //Get val of clicked item

    $.post("functions/cart.php", {prodID : prodID}, function(data){
        if (data.length>0){ 
            $("#search_results").show();    
            $("#search_results").html(data);
        } 
})
```

---

Although i would use only one button, without a form like this.

Php:

```
echo "<button name='prodID' class='shop_prod_list_kundvagn addcart' data-prodid='".$rad['prodID']."' value='Add' />";
```

Javascript:

```
$(".addcart").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var prodID = $(this).data('prodid');

    $.post("functions/cart.php", {prodID : prodID}, function(data){
        if (data.length>0){ 
            $("#search_results").show();    
            $("#search_results").html(data);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Many many thanks, works fine!!! think you forgot </button> in html, yet again thanks!

Comment: I thought the `/>` close was enough. Glad to help. Would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to pick out the value is not correct.

In theory you are supposed to have unique id's - so thats your first issue to resolve.

Secondly you need to find a better way to locate the value you are interested in.

My suggestion would be to add a button within each form and call it 'submit'.

On this button you add a data attribute that contains the product id.

With an onclick handler on this button you'll be able to get the data attribute directly.

Example which is not tested:

```
<button data-prodid="XYZ" onlcick="handleclick()">submit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(this).data('prodid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you should not have duplicate IDs on the same page.

In this case, all three of your products have the id of "prodID". So in your JavaScript, when you getElementById, you will always get the first ID with that name.

There are many solutions for this. For example, you could add the product ID to the ID of the button, like `'id="addcart_' . $rad['prodID'] . '"'`

You'd then parse that ID upon form submit to determine which product was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ - to pass hidden values.

But your solution is much simpler :)